# How to find rows from less than 6 months ago in PHP and MySQL, Month By Month

Tags: php, mysql, loops

i have this SQL sentence when execute in phpmyadmin result is fine:

```
SELECT COUNT(cid) as total from courier where pick_date > DATE_SUB(now(),
INTERVAL 6 MONTH) group by year(pick_date), MONTH(pick_date)
```

Result:

```
COUNT(cid)

221
380
368
315
140
204
54
```

But when i try in PHP only obtain one count

```
$out = array();
$sql="SELECT COUNT(cid) as total from courier where pick_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) group by year(pick_date), MONTH(pick_date)";
$pquery=$pdo->query($sql);
$prow=$pquery->fetch_all(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$out[]=$prow['total'];
echo implode( ", ", $out );
```

Actual Result: 221

```
Expected:

221
380
368
315
140
204
54
```

Thanks in Advance... :)

Comment: Here cid`s area different & you are getting its count only... Please post the result with cid`s also... so its will be easy to find solution

Comment: is `->fetch_all()` your wrapper function? as the standard is [`->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Also, since `->fetchAll()` returns an array of arrays, you have to loop over the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code:

```
$out = array();
$sql="SELECT COUNT(cid) as total from courier where pick_date > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) group by year(pick_date), MONTH(pick_date)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$out = array();
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $value) {
    $out[] = $value['total'];
}
echo implode(", ", $out );
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Good Luck @joseav.